# Benchmarking Redshift Queries

Tags: amazon-redshift, benchmarking

I want to know how long my queries take to execute, so that I can see whether my changes improve the runtime or not.

Simply timing the executing of the whole query is unsuitable, since this also takes into account the (highly variable) time spent waiting in an execution queue.

Redshift provides the [STL_WLM_QUERY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_WLM_QUERY.html) table that contains separate columns for queue wait time and execution time. However, my queries do not reliably show up in this table. For example if I execute the same query multiple times the number of corresponding rows in STL_WLM_QUERY is often much smaller than the number of repetitions. Sometimes, but not always, only one row is generated no matter how often I run the query. I suspect some caching is going on.

Is there a better way to find the actual execution time of a Redshift query, or can someone at least explain under what circumstances exactly a row in STL_WLM_QUERY is generated?

Answer (score 2):

My tips

1. If possible, ensure that your query has not waited at all, if it has
   there should be a row on stl_wlm_query. If it did wait - then rerun
   it.
2. Run the query once to compile it, then a second time to benchmark
   it. compile time can be significant
3. Disable the new query result caching feature (if you have it yet -
   you probably don't)
   ([https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-redshift-introduces-result-caching-for-sub-second-response-for-repeat-queries/)](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-redshift-introduces-result-caching-for-sub-second-response-for-repeat-queries/)